# How to replace "set rowcount"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Currently on SQL Server 2008/R2. I just read here that "set rowcount" is being deprecated in some post 2012 release: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

We have some legacy code that uses it presumably to delete small chunks of data and to minimize locking in our nightly "Data Purge" job.

Without rowcount, I would have to use "top xxx" instead?

```
  set rowcount 1000 /* Only delete this number of rows at a time */;
  declare @short_time datetime2 = DATEADD(week,-1,SYSUTCDATETIME());


      SET @TotalRowCount = 0 
      while ( select COUNT(1) from FlightAudit with (nolock) ) > @min_row_count
      begin
            delete FlightAudit where CreatedUTC < @short_time;
            SET @SaveRowCount = @@ROWCOUNT 
            SET @TotalRowCount = @TotalRowCount + @SaveRowCount 
            if @SaveRowCount=0 break;
            print 'delete from FuelerCertificationAudit...' + convert(varchar(10),@SaveRowCount) + ' Time=' + dbo.DateOrNullToChar(getdate()) 
      end
      print 'Total deleted from FlightAudit...' + convert(varchar(10),@TotalRowCount) + ' Time=' + dbo.DateOrNullToChar(getdate())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Just remove the `set rowcount` and use

```
DELETE TOP (1000) FlightAudit
WHERE  CreatedUTC < @short_time;
```

The rest of the code can remain unchanged.

This deletes an arbitrary 1000 rows matching the `WHERE` clause (same semantics as the original query).

If you wanted to define a particular `ORDER BY` for the `TOP` then you could use

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT TOP (1000) *
         FROM   FlightAudit
         WHERE  CreatedUTC < @short_time
         ORDER  BY CreatedUTC)
DELETE FROM T;
```